# why action parameter converts to query string in asp net core

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I have this method in ASP.NET Core:

```
   [HttpDelete("id:int")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delelte(int id)
    {
       // do sth
    }
```

Now when I call this api via swagger the generated url is :

```
https://localhost:44357/api/mycontroller/id:int?id=2
```

I expected to have a url without querystring like `api/mycontroller/2`

The problem is that I want to call this api from code and in code I call it like this `api/mycontroller/2` but it return 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpDelete("id:int")]
```

Should be

```
[HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
```

The parameters are encapsulated in angle brackets `{}` with optional constraints like `int`. Everything outside of that is considered a static part of the route url.

See also [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to come from the way you have fromatted your HttpDelete attribute.

Try to format it this way instead :

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
```